# javascript regexp replace stuff wrapped in quotes?

Tags: javascript, regex

I know some basic regexp, but here's the thing. Every charachter will be enclosed in spans. 
I want things that are surrounded by quotes to be replaced, so, something like `"something"` would actually be

```
<span class="charachter">"</span>
<span class="charachter">s</span>
<span class="charachter">o</span>
<span class="charachter">m</span>
<span class="charachter">e</span>
<span class="charachter">t</span>
<span class="charachter">h</span>
<span class="charachter">i</span>
<span class="charachter">n</span>
<span class="charachter">g</span>
<span class="charachter">"</span>
```

(The line breaks are there just for convinience. It's just 1 long line in the real thing.)

How do I make that into:

```
<span class="charachter green">"</span>
<span class="charachter green">s</span>
<span class="charachter green">o</span>
<span class="charachter green">m</span>
<span class="charachter green">e</span>
<span class="charachter green">t</span>
<span class="charachter green">h</span>
<span class="charachter green">i</span>
<span class="charachter green">n</span>
<span class="charachter green">g</span>
<span class="charachter green">"</span>
```

? I'm using regexp because that "something" might be anything.

BTW: The use of jQuery in the code is allowed

**There are more things that are .charachter class that I don't want to add class "green" to, just the ones enclosed in quotes**

Comment: Why do you need to use regex? All you are doing in your example is adding a CSS class, right? Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the misspelling intentional?

Comment: Anyway, a simple regular expression that *will* do that is `s/"charachter"/"charachter green"/` (it's a specific form, not a general form so it avoids the issue of " nesting/counting). Of course, this also has the potential to do much more. Also, the last bold statement makes ZERO sense :)

Comment: The closest I can come to making sense of your question is this: given an input string "something", you want to look for a set of adjacent spans in your document that spell out the input string one letter at a time and (assuming you find such a set) update each of the spans by adding the class "green" to it (without removing the existing "charachter" class). Is that right? Or is your code supposed to create the spans in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work, depending on the complexity of your page:

```
var quotes = $("span.charachter:contains('\"')");
for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length - 1; i++) {
    quotes.eq(i).nextUntil(quotes.eq(++i)).andSelf().addClass("green");
}
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3SRdD/2/

This assumes that:

- A `span.charachter` will only ever contain one single character.
- You will never have an unmatched quote.
- The following siblings of a `span.charachter` with a quote are always more `span.charachter` elements, at least until the closing quote.

Comment: @nnnnnn - That's not an assumption - the question explicitly states: "BTW: The use of jQuery in the code is allowed".

Comment: My apologies, obviously I missed that (I was looking for the jQuery tag).

Answer (score 1):

Simple jquery solution - something like?

```
$(".character").addClass("green")
```

Comment: +1 (although it might not apply, the context is vague) because regular expressions are not [always] the answer.

Comment: I have added some strong text in my question, please read. I'm sorry for my vague context. I only want things in quote to add class green

Comment: Please define "things in quote". Sorry for my poor understanding, but it will help it cite an example of what you want to be covered and what not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if your pattern looks like this `/"(.*)"/` you should place a question mark **?** after the star ***** to make it ungreedy, like this `/"(.*?)"/`

also checkout [repeating section on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it reliably, because " shows up inside the span as well.

But if you willing to be more restrictive you can search for `<span class=".*"` - but it will only match tags that look exactly like that.